# Implementação de uma LinkedList

Tags: java, estrutura-de-dados

Estou tendo problemas para implementar uma `LinkedList` para a disciplina de *Estrutura de Dados*. O código está dando este erro:

> Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.NullPointerException`, e não entendo bem o porque. Segue código:

#### Classe principal Program

```
package br.com.magnoliamedeiros.linkedlist;

import java.util.Iterator;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        LinkedList<String> minhaLista = new LinkedList<String>();

        minhaLista.add("Magnolia");
        minhaLista.add("Maria");

        Iterator<String> it = minhaLista.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            String s = it.next();
            System.out.println(s);
        }     
    }
}
```

#### Classe Node

```
package br.com.magnoliamedeiros.linkedlist;

public class Node<T> {
    Node<T> proximo;
    Node<T> anterior;
    T valor;

    public void setProximo(Node<T> proximo){
        this.proximo = proximo;
    }
    public Node<T> getProximo(){
        return proximo;
    }
    public void setAnterior(Node<T> anterior){
        this.anterior = anterior;
    }
    public Node<T> getAnterior(){
        return anterior;
    }
    public void setValor(T valor){
        this.valor = valor;
    }
    public T getValor(){
        return valor;
    }

}
```

#### Classe LinkdekList

```
package br.com.magnoliamedeiros.linkedlist;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class LinkedList<T> implements java.util.List<T> {
    private Node<T> inicio;
    private Node<T> fim;

    @Override
    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(T e) {
        Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>();
        newNode.setValor(e);

        if(inicio == null){
            inicio = newNode;
        }
        if(fim == null){
            fim = newNode;
        }else{
            fim.setProximo(newNode);
            newNode.setAnterior(fim);
            fim = newNode;
        }
        return true;
        //return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends T> c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends T> c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public T get(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public T set(int index, T element) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int index, T element) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public T remove(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int indexOf(Object o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<T> listIterator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<T> listIterator(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public <string> string[] toArray(string[] a) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


}
```

#### Classe LinkedListIterator

```
package br.com.magnoliamedeiros.linkedlist;

public class LinkedListIterator<T> implements java.util.Iterator<T> {
    private Node<T> proximoNode = null;

    LinkedListIterator(Node<T> inicio){
        proximoNode = inicio;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return proximoNode != null;
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        T valor = proximoNode.getValor();
        proximoNode = proximoNode.getProximo();
        return valor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O seu método que retorna o `Iterator` não está implementado. Ele está assim no código que você apresentou:

```
@Override
public Iterator<T> iterator() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return null;
}
```

Então cabe implementação para que seu método `main` funcione.

A propósito, é interessante que você coloque o `stack trace` inteiro do erro, como neste caso:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at padrao.Teste.main(Teste.java:19)
```

Comment: Modifiquei:

@Override
 public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new LinkedListIterator<T>(inicio);
 }

Mesmo assim ainda persiste o erro... :-(

Comment: O erro que aparece é:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at br.com.magnoliamedeiros.linkedlist.Program.main(Program.java:15)

Comment: @MagShania compilei aqui com a alteração que você informou no primeiro comentário e funcionou corretamente. Tem certeza que você construiu seu programa corretamente após alterar?

Comment: Deu certo aqui também, agora o problema já é outro, ao implementar o método remove e executar não mostra nada... nem mesmo erro... segue método:

Comment: @MagShania se o problema é outro você deve abrir outra pergunta e fechar esta como resolvida.

Comment: Beleza, tudo bem, desculpe, mas como fecho?

Comment: @MagShania marque o V ao lado da reposta que te ajudou a solucionar o problema

Comment: Quem deu downvote fique a vontade para comentar qual o erro da resposta para que eu possa corrigir.